# Is it possible to embed Java code within Mule DataWeave mappings?

Tags: mule, dataweave

With DataMapper you could do something like this:

```
output.outputField = MyClass.staticMethod(input.intputField));
```

However, it doesn't seem possible to do something equivalent with DataWeave. The closest seems to be by defining your own MEL global function as described [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-dataweave-in-studio#calling-global-mel-functions-from-dataweave-code) but I'd prefer to write plain old Java code, contained within a Java class.

Comment: You won't be able to invoke java methods directly in DataWeave. There is concept in Global function, use this path to this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can use the %function in the header section of dataweave.

Answer (score 0):

If it is more than a simple oneliner I would use a global function that calls my java logic. You then call that global function from within dataweave.